# Problem with giving permissions to the Apache folder on a Raspberry Pi 3 B+ on Raspbian

Tags: apache, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I am currently trying to install an apache web server on my raspberry pi 3b+, I am an amateur and am just following a tutorial from the official website(https://raspberry-pi.fr/installer-serveur-web-raspberry-lamp/)
I wrote the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt update
sudo apt install apache2
```

These four lines didn't cause any trouble. Then, when I input this:

```
sudo chown -R pi:www-data /var/www/html/
```

I receive this error message:

```
chown: invalid user: « pi:www-data »
```

Thank you for your help